# How to prevent xarray from converting time offsets to absolute datetimes

Tags: python-xarray

I have a fairly standard weather dataset with 5 dimensions: reference time, forecast hour, z, y, and x. The forecast hours are offsets relative to the reference time. The dataset is saved to disk as one file per reference time. I would like to open the entire multifile dataset and have the forecast dimension aligned by offset, but xarray automatically converts and aligns the forecast dimension by absolute time.

There are several reasons to prefer time offsets over absolute datetimes. Using absolute time drastically increases the logical shape of the dataset because only certain forecasts are valid for each reference time. This increased shape causes the dataset to be mostly `nan`, and any user has to know about that validity through external means. Aligning the forecast by offset makes the dataset much more self describing.

#### A concrete example

I am working with the [NAM-NMM](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/north-american-mesoscale-forecast-system-nam) forecast. The forecast is released every 6 hours as a series of GRIB files, one for each forecast hour. I first open each GRIB file as a dataset using the PyNIO engine and select the variables and geographic area I want to keep. Then I add the reference time as a datetime coordinate and the forecast hour as an integer coordinate with the `units` attribute set to `'hours since {reftime}'`. (Setting the units is required for proper visualization in Panoply.) Then I concatenate all the datasets for the same reference time along the forecast dimension and save the result to disk as netCDF.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/cbarrick/b98865176450b28fb0c52f5f8c737495) of what's going on and the output of `ncdump`.

This works just fine. I can select along the forecast dimension using hour offsets. I can visualize the dataset in Panoply. And the forecast dimension looks correct in `ncdump`.

BUT when I reopen the netCDF, xarray automatically converts the forecast dimension to an absolute datetime. And when I open multiple files, the forecast dimension is aligned by absolute time rather than reference time.

How do I prevent xarray from interpreting the forecast dimension as an absolute datetime?

Comment: Please share a description of your netcdf file, e.g., the output of `ncdump -h`. A snippet of code showing how you are using with xarray would also be helpful.

Comment: It's the [NAM-NMM](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/north-american-mesoscale-forecast-system-nam) forecast. The data is released as GRIB, one for each forecast hour, which I open with the PyNIO backend. Then I rename some variables, take a geo subset, set the reftime and forecast coordinates, concat all the forecasts for the same reftime, and save to netCDF. [Here a recent `ncdump`](https://gist.github.com/cbarrick/b98865176450b28fb0c52f5f8c737495), but I am using ints for forecast here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `decode_times=False` in `xarray.open_dataset` or `xarray.open_mfdataset` will disable parsing times. This should let you customize things in whatever fashion is necessary before calling `xr.decode_cf()`, e.g.,

```
raw = xr.open_mfdataset(my_files, decode_cf=False)
raw.forecast.attrs['units'] = 'hours'
ds = xr.decode_cf(raw)
```

In particular, if you set the "units" attribute to a time unit like "hours", xarray will decode your "forecast" variable into `np.timedelta64`. This would allow you to combine multiple files along the same axes.

I suspect Panoply may be able to handle such units, too, since time interval units are appropriate for this variable, which I believe corresponds to "forecast_period" according to [CF Standard names](http://cfconventions.org/standard-names.html).